# whats the best way to put a picture frame around an image using photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

i have a photo and i want to put a "frame" around it so i can paste as a layer into a larger image and have it look like this was a photo frame hanging on a wall

is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Spend some time learning how to make and manipulate selctions, as you will never get anywhere with Photoshop otherwise.  There are loads of books, online tutorials and YouTube videos.

Comment: @paradroid - thanks for the tip, but that doesn't really help me with this question

Comment: Maybe this will then: http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=photoshop+frame&utm_source. Seriously, spend a few days with a book and you'll be amazing yourself by next week.  Once you know the Pen tool and Curves, you'll be hardcore.

Comment: In GIMP I do it by growing the image without scaling and making one side of the frame then copy pasting it several times...paradroid has a point though.

Comment: It would be better if you actually included an example otherwise you're just shooting for air

Comment: @paradroid - do you have any recommended books

Comment: @ooo: I learnt Photoshop a long time ago, and tended towards the photography side rather than graphics.  I learnt excellent things from `Martin Evening's Photoshop for Photographers v5.0`.  The latest editions of the book are much fatter, and I also have the CS3 edition which I refer to often.  http://www.photoshopforphotographers.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple method:

Just **resize the canvas** (by adding *x* amount of pixels to both the width and height of the canvas) while keeping the image centred, then save the image.  Saving the file joins the image and the blank canvas surrounding it into a single layer.

You may want to ensure the default canvas colour matches what you want for the border colour, or simply use the paint bucket to fill the blank area after saving the file.

Once you're happy with the above outcome, select all of the image, and past into your secondary image.